# Typescript toggle bool method to class field

Tags: angular, typescript

Good day fellow stackers!

I am looking to toggle the value of a *class field* with a *method*. I have an angular button which on click calls the `onSave()` *method*:

```
export class CourseComponent {
    isActive:boolean;

    onSave() {
        return this.isActive = (bool = !bool);
    }
}
```

I would like to know how do I pass a value to a class field after toggling boolean?

If anyone could be kind enough to point out the flaw in my logic and understanding I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Uh, what is `bool`?  Are you just trying to do `this.isActive = !this.isActive`?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it public and access via `.`

```
export class CourseComponent {
    public isActive: boolean;

    onSave() {
        return this.isActive = (bool = !bool);
    }
}

const obj = new CourseComponent();
obj.isActive = true;
```

Comment: thank you! My toggle bool code is still *uncreachable*: `return this.isActive = (bool = !bool);`

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?